# How to convert a 3x3 data points into matrix form

Tags: python-3.x, bash, awk, sed

I want to do some post-processing on an output file.

My command "`grep ' MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR' -A6 OUTCAR`" on the terminal prints three matrices (numbering `matrix (i)` is just to make it more clear while it was not printed from the output):

```
MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR (including local field effects in DFT)
 ------------------------------------------------------
          21.231535    -0.000000    -0.000000              ---- matix. (1)
          -0.000000    21.231535    -0.000000
          -0.000000    -0.000000    21.231535
 ------------------------------------------------------

--
 MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR (including local field effects in DFT)
 ------------------------------------------------------
          21.231535    -0.000000    -0.000000              ---- matix. (2)
          -0.000000    21.231535    -0.000000
          -0.000000    -0.000000    21.231535
 ------------------------------------------------------

--
 MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR IONIC CONTRIBUTION
 ------------------------------------------------------
           4.671391    -0.000004     0.000000              ---- matix. (3)
          -0.000004     4.671584     0.000855
           0.000000     0.000855     4.670146
 ------------------------------------------------------
```

***Below is what I want.***

I want to convert the second data grid (the first and second both are the same. So I want to convert one of them only) into a matrix form as

```
     - [21.231535,    -0.000000,    -0.000000]              ---- matix. (4). This is the same as the matrix (2) but is enclosed in `- [] ` and with `,` at the end of columns one and two.
     - [-0.000000,    21.231535,    -0.000000]
     - [-0.000000,    -0.000000,    21.231535]
```

and in the second output, I want to add second and third data points and the resultant output should be

```
     - [25.902926,    -0.000004,    -0.000000]]              ---- matix. (5). This is the sum of the matrix (1) and (2) and is enclosed in `- []` and with `,` at the end of columns one and two.
     - [-0.000004,    25.903119,    -0.000855]
     - [-0.000000,    -0.000855,    25.901681]
```

Being a novice, I could not try it on myself. So, I am posting this without my efforts.

Comment: What's the goal? Loading the data into a python matrices? Or just processing the output for generating text matrices?

Comment: just processing the output for generating text matrices.

Comment: Are you trying to generate YAML?

Comment: Any file format is okay.

Comment: @rekha, Could you please explain more on Logic part that how are you getting output?

Comment: I have a text file "OUTCAR". Using the following command on the terminal: `grep ' MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR' -A6 OUTCAR` I am getting three matrices. Out of three, I need the second matrix as such but should be enclosed in `- [   ....] and at the end of column 1st and 2nd, a `,1 should be there  while for the other matrix should be the sum of the second and the third matrix but should be enclosed in `- [   ....] and at the end of column 1st and 2nd. I have updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: Would the following logic be fine? Print all duplicate matrix (that would select **#2**) and sum the first occurrence of each matrix (that would select **#1** and **#3**). Or do you want to keep your logic as: print the first matrix and sum **#2** and **#3**

Comment: Both logics will work as matrice 1st and 2nd  are the same from my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution that makes use of `getline`, which is a kind of an anti-pattern but it allows to define a function for reading the matrices, so the main code is easier to understand, IMHO.

I define a matrix as a single-dim array with the `x,y` coordinates plus `"dimX"` and `"dimY"` as keys. The `get_matrix` and `print_matrix` custom functions deal with arrays in that format.

You can select the matrices that you want to print or sum in the `BEGIN` block.

Here's the code:

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {
        toPrint[1]
        toSum[1]
        toSum[3]
    }

    /MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR/ {

        ++id

        if ( ! (id in toPrint || id in toSum) )
            next

        ok = get_matrix( matx )

        if ( !ok )
            exit 1

        if ( id in toPrint )
            print_matrix( matx )

        if ( id in toSum ) {
            if ( ! ("dimX" in _sum) ) {
                _sum["dimX"] = matx["dimX"]
                _sum["dimY"] = matx["dimY"]
            }
            if ( matx["dimX"] != _sum["dimX"] || matx["dimY"] != _sum["dimY"] )
                exit 1
            for ( x = 1; x <= matx["dimX"]; x++ )
                for (y = 1; y <= matx["dimY"]; y++)
                    _sum[x,y] += matx[x,y]
        }
    }

    END {  print_matrix( _sum) }

    function print_matrix( matrix,    x,y ) {
        for ( y = 1; y <= matrix["dimY"]; y++ ) {
            printf( "- [" )
            for ( x = 1; x <= matrix["dimX"]; x++) {
                printf("%s%f", (x > 1 ? "," : ""), matrix[x,y])
            }
            print "]"
        }
    }

    function get_matrix( matrix,    x,y,ok ) {

        ok = 0
        while ( !ok && getline > 0 )
            ok = /---/
        if ( !ok )
            return 0

        delete matrix
        x = y = ok = 0

        while ( !ok && getline > 0 )
            if ( /---/ )
                ok = 1
            else if ( NF ) {
                if ( ! y )
                    x = NF
                else if ( x != NF )
                    return 0
                ++y
                for (x = 1; x <= NF; x++)
                    matrix[x,y] = $x
                --x
            }

        if ( !ok )
            return 0

        matrix["dimX"] = x
        matrix["dimY"] = y

        return 1
    }

' OUTCAR
```

```
- [21.231535,-0.000000,-0.000000]
- [-0.000000,21.231535,-0.000000]
- [-0.000000,-0.000000,21.231535]
- [25.902926,-0.000004,0.000000]
- [-0.000004,25.903119,0.000855]
- [0.000000,0.000855,25.901681]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `awk` to start with. It searches all unique `MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR` in the input files and sum the values:

```bash
awk '
    !_state && match($0, "MACROSCOPIC STATIC DIELECTRIC TENSOR") {
        id = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        if ( ! seen[id]++ )
            _index = _state = 1
        next
    }
    _state && /---/ {
        if ( _state == 1 )
          _state = 2
        else
          _state = 0
        next
    }
    _state == 2 {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            _sum[_index++] += $i
        _width = NF
    }
    END {
        for (i = 1; i < _index; i++) {
            if (i %_width == 1) {
              sep = ""
            }
            printf("%s%.6f", sep, _sum[i])
            sep = OFS
            if ( i %_width == 0 ) {
              print ""
            }
        }
    }
' OUTCAR
```

```
25.902926 -0.000004 0.000000
-0.000004 25.903119 0.000855
0.000000 0.000855 25.901681
```

Comment: Thanks, Fravadone, but this is not what I am looking for, want to get printed two matrices. One is what you have printed but it should be enclosed with  " - [..]"  and with "," at the end of 1st and 2nd column while in the second matrice, I the second matric as such what my command printed but it should also be enclosed with  " - [..]"  and with "," at the end of 1st and 2nd column.

Comment: Well, I wasn't clear about your expected output. The output formatting is done in the `END` block; you just have to set `OFS` to `,` modify the two `if` for them to print `[` and `]` respectively and you're done.

Comment: I could do it. But I need to print matrice second also.

Comment: What I changed is here (only bottom part):             sep = "- ["
            }
            printf(" %s%.6f", sep, _sum[i])
            sep =", "
            if ( i %_width == 0 ) {
              print "]"
            }
        }
    }
' OUTCAR